# How long do I need to wait before sending a follow up email or IM to someone in my company when they are not replying?

Tags: communication, email

An email was sent on Friday and it's now Wednesday and I have no response yet. I've seen this question asked about interviews, but this was to someone in the company I already work at. I wanted to reach out the email recipient via Skype IM.

For more context if this helps:

I was supposed to have an interview for a promotion. Five minutes into the interview, the interviewer found out I'm a contractor for my company and cut the interview saying he had to speak to HR about the hoops we would need to jump through. The interviewer emailed HR on Friday, through a response to the original email setting up the interview. I would like to IM the HR rep who sent the original email setting up the interview, but I'd like to not be a bother if I haven't waited enough time.

Comment: Do you have access to the calendars for these people? If so, I'd check - have they marked themselves as out of office or otherwise have very busy schedules?

Comment: No I don't. I have been checking their Skype status periodically since the beginning of the week and they have been available several times. At the time of writing this they were available, but now they are busy for the next five hours.

Comment: Have you considered walking to their office? Or giving them a phone call? Anything preventing you from doing that?

Comment: I would follow up with the interviewer. He may have already gotten a response from HR.

Comment: @AffableAmbler I think that's probably the best idea, because I've at least communicated with him on the phone for a short bit. I was thinking about messaging the interviewer to see if he has heard back and if not, then sending a message to the HR rep.

Answer (score -1):

Typically a full business day.    That means I'd likely just shoot over a polite email on Tuesday or Wednesday asking if they'd had a chance to think about it.     It being Wednesday, they've had a chance to address it if they took a day off on Monday, or just had a million fires to put out when they got into the office.

Answer (score -1):

**Now might be a good time (a few days after the initial email).** The question your colleague in HR is trying to figure out might take some research, so they might not have an answer for you, but could at least give you an idea of when you should expect an answer.

Alternatively, **you should consider talking to the member of HR in person or over the phone** if you need an answer quickly. If an electronic message didn't get resolved as quickly as you liked, it's a good idea to upgrade from email to a phone call or in-person conversation.